# Create a column by iterating on another column

Tags: pandas, loops, date

I have two columns, one with an ID and the orhter with transaction dates.

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2019-04-30 |
| A | 2020-12-15 |
| B | 2019-08-24 |
| B | 2019-09-29 |
| B | 2019-10-14 |

And so on...

I want to create a column that orders the date by ID.

| ID | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-04-30 | Order_1 |
| A | 2020-12-15 | Order_2 |
| B | 2019-08-24 | Order_1 |
| B | 2019-09-29 | Order_2 |
| B | 2019-10-14 | Order_3 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with add `1` with cast to strings, so possible add `Order_`:

```
df['Type'] = 'Order_' + df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

df['diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff().dt.days
```

> I got a problem, when I pivot the table, we orders the date alphabetically (Order_1, Order_10, Order_100,..) and not Order_1, Order_2. Because it is a string. Is there a way around this?

Convert values to numeric and after pivoting use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df['Type'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)

df1 = df.pivot('ID','Type','diff').add_prefix('Order_')
```

Comment: Legend! Worked perfectly.

If I put this new table in a pivot one, how do I calculate the difference between dates?

Comment: I got a problem, when I pivot the table, we orders the date alphabetically (Order_1, Order_10, Order_100,..) and not Order_1, Order_2. Because it is a string. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @FilipeCarvalho - Give me a sec.

Comment: I think I got it, just cut the 'Order_' from the name of the column, since it is irrelevant for the problem.

Still, would like help to calculate the difference between dates :)

Comment: jezrael thank you very much! That was perfect ;)